# How point wise multiplication and addition takes place in LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

timesteps=4, features=2 and LSTM(units=3)

Input to lstm will be (batch_size, timesteps, features) dimensions of the hidden State and cell state will be (None, unit in LSTM). When lstm take the input at t1 will get concatenated with the hidden State at features axis. After that it will pass through sigmoid and tanh. Now my main confusion is "how will it do the point Wise operation(addition or multiplication) with the cell state".

How I look at this is shown in the attached [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3VP8.jpg). If there's anything which I am taking wrong kindly make the correction. Thanks in advance to everyone.